# Uploading sources to nexus makes snapshot dependencies unavailable to maven

Tags: java, maven, nexus

When we do `mvn install deploy` to a repository `${repository-jars}` these dependencies can be used by others as intended.

When we **afterwards** upload sources to another repository `${repository-sources}` the dependencies are no longer resolved correctly.

```
mvn deploy:deploy-file 
   -DgroupId=foo 
   -DartifactId=bar 
   -Dversion=1.0-SNAPSHOT 
   -Dfile=target/bar-sources.jar 
   -Dpackaging=jar 
   -Durl=${url} 
   -Dclassifier=sources 
   -DrepositoryId=${repository-sources}
```

Everything looks correct in nexus and both repositories are available in a regular `Repository Group`.

The hypothesis is that maven tries to use the latest uploaded artifact and ends up downloading the `sources` jar instead somehow ignoring the `classes` modifier.  This is verified by first uploading sources and **then** do a `maven deploy` where it works as intended.

What is the correct way that allows us to upload sources in a separate job that runs after a deploy?

Comment: Is deploying them as a separate step absolutely necessary? Also I assume you are using a group repo? What does your group repo look like?

Comment: @DarthHater Yes we're using a regular `Repository Group` with both repositories in them (order appears irrelevant). Reason to keep them separate is to be absolutely sure sources are separated from binaries.

Comment: What myself and another dev think is that the group is attempting to merge the metadata between the two (because you are using a group). What you might actually try is putting them in the same repo (so they will share common metadata), and separate them using Content Selectors (I imagine you are keeping them separate for security reasons?): https://books.sonatype.com/nexus-book/reference3/admin.html#content-selectors

Comment: Makes sense, the `Download` column of the search overview lists `pom, sources.jar, pom`. Both pom files are identical.

Comment: In deeper looking via someone who is smarter than both I and the other dev, it's because you are creating two different snapshots (unique per build executed), so there are two versions of the same GA. Take a look at Content Selectors, this is akin to Repo Targets in the Nexus 2 world (I somehow assumed you are using Nexus 3, if not, take a look at Repo Targets :) )

Comment: Nexus 3 yeah. Thanks for the advice, I'll come by when I tried it proper. Meanwhile, i think your suggestion would be a good candidate for an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In examination, Maven is creating two different snapshots, and when you attempt to get latest, it's getting the newest one (which is sources) from the Group you've setup.

What you might actually try is putting them in the same repo, and separate them using [Content Selectors](https://books.sonatype.com/nexus-book/reference3/admin.html#content-selectors). This is our newer version of Repo Targets from Nexus Repository 2.